# Analog 6.0 Logformat error

Tags: apache

My Analog 6.0 is not able to recognize my access log format please find the below details and helping me correcting my log format

**My Apache log format:**

> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-Agent}i\"" combined
>
> LogFormat "%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %T %D" common
>
> LogFormat "%{Referer}i -> %U" referer
>
> LogFormat "%{User-agent}i" agent

**My Analog 6.0 Log format:**
I have tried the below two log formats

> APACHELOGFORMAT (%h %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b %T %D)
>
> LOGFORMAT (%s %j %j [%d/%M/%Y:%h:%n:%j] "%j %r %j" %c %b %T %D\n)

My access log:

> 192.168.140.253 - - [07/Mar/2016:00:12:46 -0500] "POST /XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 58 0 21359
>
> 192.168.140.253 - - [07/Mar/2016:00:12:48 -0500] "GET /XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 1670 0 7325
>
> 192.168.140.253 - - [07/Mar/2016:00:12:48 -0500] "POST /XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 58 0 8106
>
> 192.168.140.253 - - [07/Mar/2016:00:12:51 -0500] "GET //XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 1768 0 4108
>
> 192.168.140.253 - - [07/Mar/2016:00:12:52 -0500] "POST /XXXX/XXXXX/XXXXXX HTTP/1.1" 200 58 0 18648

Error:

> F:\analog_60>analog.exe
>
> analog.exe: analog version 6.0/Win32
>
> analog.exe: Warning C: Bad argument in configuration command: ignoring it:
>
> > LOGFORMAT (%S %j %j [%d/%M/%Y:%h:%n:%j] "%j%w%r%w HTTP%j" %c %b %T %D\n)
>
> analog.exe: ...cont..:   (reason: one item occurs twice in format)
>
> > (For help on all errors and warnings, see docs/errors.html)
>
> analog.exe: Warning E: Redirecting future diagnostic messages to errors.txt
>
> F:\analog_60>analog.exe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

replace `%D\n` by `%j`

and use this syntax in analog.cfg

`LOGFORMAT (%S %j %j [%d/%M/%Y:%h:%n:%j] "%j %r %j" %c %b %t %j)`

I was able to get stat with your access.log lines

note:

If you want to activate Processing Time Report
add `PROCTIME ON` at the end of your analog.cfg

Hope it helps